# Multithreading in React Native / Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a graphics application that runs at 60 FPS. I want to offload most of the logic to a new thread that doesn't interrupt the JS thread because when the JS thread is interrupted, the FPS drops.

How can I spawn another thread in React Native / Expo?